# How can i read the texture in the area between the black lines? (Painting)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to read sprite/texture to get areas between blacklines in the first black and white photo. I don't know is it efficient but i am trying to do painting with numbers like in the third photo. I need to add numbers to all areas and i need to match the colors with original colored photo.     Thanks.

[Black & White Image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JExFf.png)

[Colored Image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVTax.jpg)

[Numbers Added] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAxRQ.png)

Comment: So .. what have you tried? We are not here for implement something for you but to help with a specific question regarding a specific implementation...

Comment: @derHugo I tried to read texture. I found a method to filling pixels. I am trying something else. I don't want implementation. I just don't know how can i do this and i am currently searching & reading the documents. I am trying to find the possible and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm you need is a 'flood fill' algorithm. Given a starting pixel, it will find all the pixels in a closed area. You would need to do this repeatedly until all the pixels in the image have been found.
There are lots of implementations for flood fill algorithms online.

So your routine could be something like-

1. Create an array of int's that stores which group each pixel is in. 0 means it's not been found yet.
2. Pick an unassigned pixel, and floodfill. Assign all the found pixels to a group.
3. Repeat 2 until all the pixels are assigned a group.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I will try it and post the result.